# Apple Developer Team Roles for contractors - text clarification

Tags: ios

On this page: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/, under "Apple Developer Program Team Roles", it says for a Member: "Available only to developers enrolled as an organization".

I am confused about this text.  If there is a company developer account, registered as an organization, that account will be the Team Agent.

Now, if that company wants to add some members, say 3rd party contractors, do new company-specific developer accounts need to be created for each of the contractors, even if they have existing individual developer accounts?

There is some discussion of contractors here: https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/, but it doesn't discuss the need for contractors to be "enrolled as an organization".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do new company-specific developer accounts need to be created for each of the contractors, even if they have existing individual developer accounts?

It isn't clear what you mean by "accounts". A developer needs only one Apple Developer Program membership. But if the developer is a member of more than one team (e.g. developing and distributing apps under his own name, but also working for some other organization), then yes, those are two separate teams and two distinct logins.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize there was a distinction between membership and account.  So the third party developer, if he already has a membership at $99/yr, does not need to have another $99/yr membership then?  Do they really need a distinct login, if the organization account has sent an invitation to the individual's email address (say a contractor who uses his own email)?  Thanks

Comment: "So the third party developer, if he already has a membership at $99/yr, does not need to have another $99/yr membership then?" Correct! — My experience is that yes, to work as a contractor for a company, if you are going to be able to perform tasks under that company's name, as a team member, you'll need a login for that team. Of course, another possibility is just to send the code back and forth, but then you're not a team member.